# Insert Russian characters mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8

I'm using mysql database and php to insert russian characters into a table.

I'm using:

```
$conn->set_charset('utf-8');
```

into my .php page to set charset to utf-8 but, when I try to print the DB charset with:

```
echo "set name:".$conn->character_set_name();
```

it shows

> set name:latin1

I've set my Table to:

> utf8mb4_unicode_ci

but nothing change.

Printing the passed text from the ajax request, I can see the text written correctly.

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you aren't checking the return value of `mysqli::set_charset()`. It must be returning `false` because `utf-8` is not a valid encoding name in MySQL; the correct name is `utf8` (no dash). Or, even better, `utf8mb4`.

You can get a list of supported encodings with:

```
SHOW COLLATION;
```